# Degrees of Freedom in R qf command?

Tags: r, anova

The command to look up the critical value for an F test in R Studio is cited as 
    qf(1-alpha,df1,df2) 
Does the df1 and df2 refer to the between groups degrees of freedom and the total degrees of freedom, or is it the between groups df and the within groups df?

For example, if I'm testing men and women (2 groups)'s hearing scores and I have a total of 100 scores, am I asking R studio to find the critical F value at the .05 alpha by typing:
    qf(.05,1,100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df1` is the degrees of freedom of the numerator, and `df2` is the degrees of freedom in the denominator.

One-way ANOVA uses "between group" as the numerator and "within group" as the denominator.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried all the permutations manually the results were too close to figure out what was happening.